# Rubocop: Use next to skip iteration

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I am getting `Style/Next: Use next to skip iteration.` from Rubocop for code that does something like this (using a very contrived example):

```
tasks_running = [{ name: 'task1', done: false }, { name: 'task2', done: false }]
tasks_done = []

tasks_running.each do |task|
  if task[:done]
    unless tasks_done.include? task
      tasks_done << task
      next
    end
  end
end
```

I *am* using next to skip iteration just within a nested condition. I don't quite understand how to satisfy this criteria.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think is complaining because you could use next in case `tasks_done` includes the current task from the block, and otherwise, push that task to the tasks_done array:

```
tasks_running.each do |task|
  if task[:done]
    next if tasks_done.include?(task)
    tasks_done << task
  end
end
```

In your case, the next statement is being evaluate always, since is the last expression within the block, it does all what it must do, and just the continues with the iteration, is as it wouldn't be there.

```
tasks_running.each do |task|
  if task[:done]                     # If true
    unless tasks_done.include?(task) # If true
      tasks_done << task             # Do this
      next                           # And jump to the next element
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yup, that was it, using `next if`. I understand now that breaking out of the loop like that will have the same effect as the `unless` did.